# Return result of a function into the run time script

Tags: powershell

I have two powershell scripts, one with a function to check the value of a variable "name" which is passed as an argument. If it doesn’t match “John”, the result is 2 and else, the result is 0 (included within the function).

Here is the function script:

```
Function test {

    Param (
        $name = $(throw "need -name"),
        $result = 0         
    )

    Process {
        if($name -ne "John") {
            Write-Host "Name is incorrect"
            $result = 2 
        } else {
            Write-Host "Student is correct"
        }
    }  
}
```

The second script calls this function and runs as -

```
Import-Module C:\function.ps1
test -name Sandra
```

Now I wanted to return the result (or a status) into the second script from the function, and add some more conditions into the second script based on the result. What are the changes required in the script or function to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are new to PowerShell, so here are some hints for you:

1. You should work with [Approved Verbs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx) e. g. change your function
   name to `Test-StudentName`.
2. There is a [language integrated support for parameter handling](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx).
3. [Using Write-Host is almost always wrong](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).

So you script could look something like this:

```
function Test-StudentName
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        $Name
    )

    if ($name -ne 'John') 
    {
        Write-Output 2
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<#
.Synopsis
   Short description
.DESCRIPTION
   Long description
.EXAMPLE
   Example of how to use this cmdlet
.EXAMPLE
   Another example of how to use this cmdlet
#>
function Test-Name
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        # Parameter Name help description
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        [string]
        $Name
    )

    Begin
    {
    }
    Process
    {

        if($name -ne "John") {
            Write-Host "Name is incorrect"
            2 
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Student is correct"
            0
        }
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

and then you "dot source"

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\joshua> cd .\Desktop\
PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> . .\Test-Name.ps1
PS C:\Users\joshua\Desktop> Test-Name -Name Sandra
Name is inccorrect
2
```

The "dot sourcing" part is ". .\Test-Name.ps1". Or you can save the file as .psm1 -- that would be the most simplistic way to create a module -- and import it

PS
and yep, the usage of Write-Host is highly discouraged though not so much in powershell version 5